# group by date with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp

I have a table `Commande` which contains `prestataire_id` ,`date` ,`heure` ,... so I want to regroup the table by date. I tried this

```
$commande = $this->Commande->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Commande.prestataire_id' => $this->request->data['prestataire_id']),'order' =>    array('Commande.date' => 'DESC')));
```

the json response is like that

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "Commande trouvé",
    "data": {
        "get_Mission": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "id": "475",
                        "date": "2018-04-20",
                        "heure": "10:00:00",
                        "date_created": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure_created": "17:11:39",
                        "date_accepted": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure_accepted": "17:12:35",
                        "delai": "00:00:56",
                        "date_fin": "0000-00-00",
                        "heure_fin": "00:00:00",

                    },


                },
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "id": "476",
                        "date": "2018-04-20",
                        "heure": "10:07:00",
                        "date_created": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure_created": "17:13:12",
                        "date_accepted": "0000-00-00",
                        "heure_accepted": "00:00:00",
                        "delai": "0",
                        "date_fin": "0000-00-00",
                        "heure_fin": "00:00:00",

                    },

                },

                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "id": "477",
                        "date": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure": "17:13:00",
                        "date_created": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure_created": "17:13:48",
                        "date_accepted": "2018-04-19",
                        "heure_accepted": "17:14:23",
                        "delai": "00:00:35",
                        "date_fin": "0000-00-00",
                        "heure_fin": "00:00:00",

                    },

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I want them to be regrouped by date like data `["2018-04-20"]-> {commande,commande}`  ,`["2018-04-19"]->{"commande}` any suggestion ?

Comment: The result of your `find` operation is a collection, so you can use [groupBy](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::groupBy) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is setting the month as your array key.

```
    foreach($examples as $example){
        $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($example['Model']['date']));
        $exampleArray[$month][] = $example;
    }
```

And re-use your $exampleArray after setting it.

Comment: thank you .. this is what i'm looking for... it's date not data change it